# Mesh not rendered in Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, mesh, makehuman

I tried all answers from Internet, press <kbd>W</kbd> - "Clear All Restrict Render", uncheck my post processing - "Compositing", recalculate my UV, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, switching back to CPU render, switch to blender render, etc., none of them works in this case. NOt sure if this is because I import the object from makehuman. My object view, material view and render view attached.

Material view:

[image]

Object view:

[image]

Who knows any other trick I should try?

[image: Render result]

Comment: Can you post your file?

Comment: Please do the following. Show the layer of the dark ribbed body. Show the render layer settings.  Someone may move picture of links to the main question.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshots, I see that the only light source that is present in the scene is the default point lamp.[image: .]

It looks like this is not enough to light up your robot. Maybe try changing that to a sun lap, or boost the power of the overall lighting in the *World* settings.

Comment: Given the appearance of the render he posted, it is not very likely the issue has to do with insufficient lighting.

Comment: @MikeMetcalf  Why not?  To me it looks like the render is missing a light source.  And there aren't any visible in the scene.

Comment: @PGMath  You are likely correct in saying that the scene needs another light source. What I'm thinking though, is that even without another light source the missing exoskeleton would still be visible as a black silhouette in his render. The inner suit *is* visible in the render, but the exoskeleton is not visible at all. If this was a missing light issue, I would expect the entire scene to be pitch black.

Comment: I agree with what atomicbezierslinger has implied... this could probably be a problem with render layers. Seeing the scene and render layers may shed some light on this.

Comment: @MikeMetcalf  Good point, I did not notice the exoskeleton.  Though it doesn't look like render layers are at fault as he does not have objects on any other layers (look at the bottom of the first two screenshots).

Comment: @MikeMetcalf I think the best thing to do for the author would be to post his .blend so that tests can easily be done by several people and the problem will have more chances to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but in case someone else has a similar issue, this might help. 
I just ran into this issue my self. My particular instance, in Object View>Duplication, setting was set to Group. Set it to None and my object renders now. I basically had it set to an empty group.